# How to split a dictionary into single-key dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict with *n* keys.
The problem is I don't want a single dictionary, but a list of dictionaries per single key-value pair.

For example:

```
d = {'a' : -15, 'b' : -71.8333, 'c' : 'a'}
```

The output I want:

```
[{'a' : -15},
 {'b' : -71.8333},
 {'c' : 'a'}]
```

Comment: Are you looking for ``[{k:v} for k, v in kwargs.items()]``?

Answer (score 0):

You can [iterate over the dict's key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) using [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and make a new dict from each one:

```py
d = {'a' : -15, 'b' : -71.8333, 'c' : 'a'}

dicts = []
for key, value in d.items():
    dicts.append({key: value}
```

Or as a list-comprehension:

```py
dicts = [{key: value} for key, value in d.items()]
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
d = {'a' : -15, 'b' : -71.8333, 'c' : 'a'}

for i, o in d.items():
    print({i: o})
```

Will give:

```
{'a': -15}
{'b': -71.8333}
{'c': 'a'}
```

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Not sure if that's rewriting. The question is still the same. The `kwargs` was simply irrelevant (it is just a dict and doesn't add anything to the question). Anyway, at this point this feels like a lost cause. I was just trying to somehow turn this into a canonical as I couldn't find a matching duplicate but maybe it's *too basic* to even be a question...